# In-app Billing promotion for users who have bought something in another app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

We have two apps who has premium features that are unlocked by In-app purchase. One app is mostly used in winter and the other in summer.
For billing we are using [Google Play Services In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html).
We would like to give 50% off *(by allowing to buy cheeper product)* for premium features in one app for users that have already bought premium in the other.

***The question is: How to get information in application A from application B about purchases in B?***

***First idea***
We've considered using hidden file stored in device which has info that indicates if user has premium in one app so we can read it form the other.
But there are few drawbacks in this solution:

1. this solution is not really secure due to file creation/edition possibility.
2. user has multiple devices and we can not get access to this file from all of them
3. if we put update for one app (eg winter app) users most likely will not open it until next season and the hidden file will not be created.

***Second idea*** was to create [ContentProviders](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) in both apps to share info from internally (DB, SharedPrefs) stored data about purchases status.
This solution solves problems 1st and 3rd from first solution but the 2nd remains.

We don't have any sign in/server side system in our apps so we cannot store it in server backend.

We wondered if there is possibility to use In App Billing api to solve our problem? Or maybe there is some other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use purchases for 'all devices' + 'sequre' + 'several apps' without your own server the only solution I would suggest is to use [Firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). You can share Firebase data between several applications.

Nonetheless, in this case you have to use internet connection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

It could be solution in some cases but unfortunately, we predict that most of the users of our 'winter app' will not open it until the next winter season. So even if we send the app update containing Firebase connection, we will have to wait until next season, when they start using it again, to reach the data.

Comment: You can silent update and send remote notification @mirekkomis

Comment: @mirekkomis you have to update your 'winter app' to make any connection between new and old apps